# display the server uploaded image using image control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, button, file-upload

my question is that how can i immediately display the server-side uploaded image [image being uploaded at a button click] ?
upload done using fileupload control.
image retrieval expected using image control.

below is the part of my code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploaded images/"+FileUpload1.FileName));
}
```

this code successfully uploads the image to "uploaded images" folder in the server.
but i failed to retrieve it to display as soon as it is uploaded.

below is what i tried, which never gave any programming error, though it never gave the 
result too!

```
Image1.ImageUrl = (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName)).ToString();
```

help expected.
regards.

Comment: Try: `Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/UploaddedImages" + FileUpload1.FileName;` change the relative path to fir your needs

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't assign local pathname as source for uploaded image.
Try something like

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "uploaded images/"+FileUpload1.FileName;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string imgPath = this.ResolveUrl("~/uploaded images/" + FileUpload1.FileName");
Image1.ImageUrl = imgPath;
```

Here's a [full discussion](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) of ASP.NET and image path issues.